# What database design could be used for linkable text?

Tags: database-design

If the text has a reference to a person, that needs to link to the person entity, if it has a reference to a country that links to the country entity.

The only thing that sprung to mind is to drop all the text in the DB and use some kind of parsing after the fact, eg database column contains an entry like this "[PersonEntityID6] is from [CountryEntityID6]"

Comment: This sounds like quite a large job (how many actual names does someone have? First + last, First+Middle+Last or more?). Using Full-Text indexes may be an easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question mainly about the design of the database to store those relationships, or is it about finding which text contains which names and countries? Anyway, both appear solvable.

First, have a database like

```
person(id, name), with an index on name,
country(id, name), with an index on name
text(id, title, full text only if needed)
person_in_text(id, person_id, text_id, position in text if needed)
country_in_text, similar
```

To analyze a text:

```
for each word in the text
   select name from person where name like word%
   for each person found
      if substring of text starting on current position equals name
         insert text_id, person_id into person_in_text
   ... same for country
```

Depending on the length of the text and the count of persons and countries, it might be better to load each person and perform a substring search of the person name in the text; same for country.